# Google Gmail API Pricing

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api

I'm using the Gmail API in a .Net project using the client_secret.json file.

Is that totally free, or is there any cost we need to pay for using Gmail API?

Also how long is the client_secret.json valid? Is there any expiry of the file?

Answer (score 7):

The Gmail API, like Gmail itself, is (currently) a free service from Google.

(Note that Google *does* offer additional features for various apps, and charges for those features.  See "Gsuite":  https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html?tab_activeEl=tabset-companies)

There are quota (usage) limits on the API.

For client-secrets.json (credentials used for server-to-server authentication), there is no expiration.  Of course, a given client secret will stop working if you revoke it (delete it) through the Google developer console.

Answer (score 5):

There is no billing marked for the Gmail API however there are usage limits: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

Comment: Does this mean that you can send 1 billion emails a day, as it says in the quota limits, or quota units is something else. What does a quota unit equal to?

Comment: No, you have 250 quota units (QU) per user per second. Each of the methods REST have a different limit. For instance, messages.send 100 QU, so, you can send max 2 messages per second. So, 86400 seconds per day and around 172k per day. However, I think they will block you if you send another max quota per hour.

Answer (score -5):

The previous answers date back to 2018. Since then Google has updated its policies. Gmail API can be used freely for development purposes, but they charge a hefty one-time fee for production. For more info refer to this [blog](https://www.parakhjs.codes/blogs/google-apis-faq):

Comment: The blog link is broken.

Comment: Perhaps they are talking about restricted scopes, which require an annual 3rd party security review. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/restricted-scope-verification#understand-restricted-scopes